# How to make user see some of navigation menu items?

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I have a page to create users.
I want, when creating the user, to specify the items that he is entitled to see from the navigation menu, through a list that includes all the navigation menu items

I tried to do that using apex_application_list_entries

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, I don't like your approach.

Consider **authorization**.

- create different roles, such as `admin` (who will see everything), `manager` (who will see many things, but not all of them), `clerk` (who will se only stuff related to their job), etc.
- every user you create should have one of these roles
- create a function which accepts e.g. `:APP_USER` and returns their role
- create number of authorization schemes (in Apex) which use previously created function
- in Apex, set "Authorization Scheme" property for each **page** and navigation menu **list entry** which will prevent unauthorized access

Doing so, you won't have to let every user see any particular page itself - authorization will take care about it.

Mind you: if Apex application has 150 pages, you'll have to pick any number of pages one-by-one for every new user, and there's no guarantee that you'll remember which pages exactly belong to page set which is supposed to be accessed by that user.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create  a Dynamic List then set it to be your Navigation Menu List in app shared component.

You can use the following query that fetch the list items from database schema.

```
select level level_value,
        menu_name label_value,
        apex_page.get_url(p_page => module_id) target_value,
        null is_current,
        icon_html image_value
    from (
        select distinct(menu_id), parent_menu_id, module_id, menu_name, icon_html, menu_seq
        from system_menu 
        where user_id = :APEX_USER_ID
    )
START WITH parent_menu_id IS null
CONNECT BY PRIOR menu_id = parent_menu_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY MENU_SEQ
```

The *system_menu* table ddl described as:

```
CREATE TABLE  "SYSTEM_MENU" 
   (    "MENU_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PARENT_MENU_ID" NUMBER, 
    "MODULE_ID" NUMBER, 
    "NAME_AR" NVARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME_EN" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "ICON_HTML" NVARCHAR2(255), 
    "IS_NUMBER" NUMBER(22,1),
    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(255),
    "MENU_SEQ" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "SYSTEM_MENU_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("MENU_ID")
   )
```

To understand more about the DYNAMIC LISTS read this [ORACLE APEX DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/htmdb/creating-dynamic-lists.html) page